# pandas time stamp correction

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have 2 time-series files I wanted to merge both. I can do the merging but the real issue is the Format of timestamp in both files.

First file: `"2014-12-14 00:10:00"`
Second file: `"3/30/2015 8:30"`

I'd prefer to go with second file time stamp format.

When I tried to merge I'm getting below error (of course it's expected one because of the timestamp issue):

```
timeseries = pd.merge(scada, met_all, on='date_time', how='inner')
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert each (from strings) to pandas Timestamp/datetime64.

```
In [11]: pd.to_datetime("2014-12-14 00:10:00")
Out[11]: Timestamp('2014-12-14 00:10:00')

In [12]: pd.to_datetime("3/30/2015 8:30")
Out[12]: Timestamp('2015-03-30 08:30:00')
```

Note: `to_datetime` also accepts a format option to be more specific.

This works on Series/columns too:

```
In [13]: pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(["2014-12-14 00:10:00"]))
Out[13]:
0   2014-12-14 00:10:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```